# ¿Cómo corregir este error NumberFOrmatException procesando un CSV?

Tags: java

Trato de convertir datos String a Double. Los datos String los cargo de un .csv y los separo con `split` pero me arroja el error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "200"`

Lo que contiene el arreglo `art[3]` son puros números, no entiendo por qué me marca ese error.

```
    double p= fe.getPrecio();

    p = Double.parseDouble(art[3]);
    
    int ex = fe.getExis();

    ex = Integer.parseInt(art[5]);
    
    for(int j = 0; j < art.length; j++)

    {
        System.out.println(new ArticuloP(art[0], art[1], art[2], art[4],p, ex));
    }
```

**//lo que contiene el arreglo art[3] son puros números**

Comment: Hola. Por favor ve a [edit] y añade la traza de error completa.

Comment: Necesitamos ver qué formato tienen esos números en el excell, ya que si sigue este formato: 17,25, por ejemplo, en java no es un formato correcto, ya que el separador es un punto, si no es ese el problema sino que está en este formato: 17, en teoría no debería haber problema, pero necesitamos saber qué numeros hay en ese CSV

Answer (score 1):

> *me arroja el error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "200"*

Puede ocurrir porque existen caracteres en blanco alrededor del texto. Por ejemplo, un caracter de tabulación, un caracter de salto de línea, etc. Puedes utilizar el método `trim()` de la clase String para eliminar caracteres en blanco al principio y al final del texto. Por ejemplo, `p = Double.parseDouble(art[3].trim());`

### Caso: CSV con tabulación alrededor del texto.

Vamos a simular una fila en formato CSV mediante una variable `String`. La fila contiene 3 números y están separadas por `;`. El segundo número tiene "basura" alrededor (un tabulador).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csv = "1;\t2;3";
        String[] data = csv.split(";");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            Integer num = Integer.valueOf(data[i]);
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
```

La ejecución del programa anterior arroja la excepción cuando trata de convertir el segundo texto a número:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "    2"`

### Solución: eliminar caracteres en blanco mediante método `trim()`

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csv = "1;\t2;3";
        String[] data = csv.split(";");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            Integer num = Integer.valueOf(data[i].trim()); // <---- trim()
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string

indica que tratas de convertir un valor no numérico a numérico, en este caso indica "200" que es númerico, pero seguramente tienes algún tipo de carácter que hace que la conversión lo considere no numérico.

En este caso te recomiendo usar un método el cual, validaría si existen espacios en los extremos da la cadena y los eliminaría y en caso de error entregaría un valor de 0.

```
public static Double getNumericValue(String number){
    Double result = 0.0;
    try{
        if(number != null){
          number = number.trim();
          result = Double.parseDouble(number);               
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println("NFException value: " + number);
    }
    return result;
}
```

usalo de esta forma:

```
//p = Double.parseDouble(art[3]);
  p = getNumericValue(art[3]);
```